# SQLite Out of Memory when preparing insert statement

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, insert

I have a problem with my app it opens this database and selects rows from it ok,

Then when I want to add new rows using the following code and I always get the following problem at the execution of the `prepare_V2`.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'out of memory''
```

code is .....

```
static sqlite3 *database = nil;                 
static sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil; 


- (BOOL)addUserprofile {

    addStmt = nil;  // set to force open for testing
    database = nil; // set to force creation of addstmt for testing

    if (database == nil) {  // first time then open database
        NSString *databaseName = @"UserProfile.db";
        // Use editable database paths
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];   
        NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        NSLog(@"path = %@",databasePath);

        NSLog(@"opening Database");
        sqlite3 *database;
        // Open the database from the users filessytem
        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Database Open");
            }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Database did not open");
        }

    }

    if(addStmt == nil) {

NSLog(@"Creating add stmt");
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Profile (ProfileName) VALUES(?)";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"** Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            success = NO;
            return success;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [ProfileName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Comment: The error message is "Error while creating update statement" whereas your code says "Error while creating add statement" -- are you sure you're debugging the code that you're running?

Comment: I figured it out myself.  The open database was not working. So i got rid of the conditional open and force it open each time and the code now works.  I had the same problem on both the add and update functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the answer.

Comment: You should set catching all exception to see where error occurred exactly!

Comment: When an open fails it's kinda important to not proceed.  You should return NO when the DB doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime, your database is being `SQLITE_BUSY` or `SQLITE_LOCKED`.

You can refer this framework to know how to do:
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Good luck!:)